# IF function and REMOVEFILTERS with related tables not working as intended - need help to fix my DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to suppress numbers <5 in my matrix visualisation and not able to work out the correct solution. My table has LGA (locality) in Rows, Year in columns and Number in Values.

To give a background, I have 17 localities and they are grouped under 2 groups, 6 localities belong to one group and 11 in the second group. I have a slicer with the 17 localities listed. The idea is when I select a locality from group 1 then the table shows data for the 6 localities in that group. I have created a dimension table to sort the localities and created a "Many to many" cardinality with single cross filter direction. It is all working perfectly. (See the attached sample file for to get a better idea).

Now I want to suppress the numbers <5 in the table. Initially I built an IF formula (Num_Suppress1) as per below and when I added the measure into my table, the table is showing all the 17 localities. I then tried to modify the formula by including REMOVEFILTERS (Num_Suppress2) but that didn't work either. I am not sure what the DAX measures are not picking the correct localities.

Here is my code and a screenshot of my sample visualisation.

I am also adding a [sample Power BI file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gu8vRmnJLPYViK4wCg?e=rA51mN) for your reference.

```
Num_Suppress1 = IF(SUM(HSUM_Results[Number]) <5, "<5",SUM(HSUM_Results[Number]))

Num_Suppress2 = IF(CALCULATE(SUM(HSUM_Results[Number]), REMOVEFILTERS(LGA[LGA_IN])) <5, "<5",SUM(HSUM_Results[Number]))
```

[image]